# Windows 11 connects to separate untagged and vlan tagged network at the same time - how do I make it stop?

Tags: windows, ipv6, vlan

I have a Windows 11 Pro machine 22H2 plugged into a network port that provides untagged network access, and a tagged VLAN for phones advertised using lldp-med.

My expectation is that Windows, in default configuration and in the absence of being told anything about the phone VLAN, should ignore the phone VLAN, but this isn't happening.

For reasons I do not understand, the Windows ethernet interface can see both the untagged LAN and the tagged phone VLAN at the same time, and then subsequently allocates itself an IPv6 SLAAC address on both networks. With two different identities, chaos ensues.

How do I tell Windows to completely ignore the phone VLAN?

Can anyone explain why this would not be default behavior?

Update:

Windows broke VLANs in 2017, and have not fixed them since.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4a9a0cd-9056-4702-931b-a8f2f64e0d8d/windows-10-talks-to-all-vlans-at-the-same-time?forum=win10itpronetworking

The registry key MonitorModeEnabled set to 1 works around the problem for Realtek cards.

**Do not put a Windows client machine and VLANs on the same network.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I tell Windows to completely ignore the phone VLAN?

Install Hyper-V and configure a vSwitch attached to the Ethernet interface.

Alternatively, open your Ethernet interface's settings through Device Manager (devmgmt.msc) and look for an 'Advanced' option to enable VLAN filtering.

> Can anyone explain why this would not be default behavior?

In the Windows driver model, as far as I know, the VLAN tag is normally converted into a separate "out of band" field (i.e. the OS sees an untagged packet + separate VLAN ID metadata) and it's the job of individual drivers to filter out unwanted tagged or untagged packets. Some drivers don't do this.

Comment: Alas Hyper-V is a sledgehammer. I see advanced under the device manager, but no "VLAN filtering" (Realtek driver from May 2021). There is VLAN Id, but no apparent way to set "untagged only". Do you know what drivers do handle VLAN traffic properly? This is impossible to google, as everything is about turning VLANs on rather than the opposite as is the case here.